# Flask tutorial - 404 Not Found

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, http-status-code-404

I just finished the Flask basic tutorial ([here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/tutorial/)) and even though I've done completed every step, when I am trying

`python flaskr.py`

what I get is a `404 Not Found` error saying

`The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.`

here is the code inside the file

```
import os
import sqlite3
from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, abort, render_template, flash

#create app
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

#load default conf and override config from an env var
app.config.update(dict(
    DATABASE=os.path.join(app.root_path, 'flaskr.db'),
    DEBUG=True,
    SECRET_KEY = 'dev key',
    USERNAME = 'admin',
    PASSWORD = 'admin'
))
app.config.from_envvar('FLASKR_SETTINGS', silent=True)

def connect_db():
    """connect to the specific db"""
    rv = sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])
    rv.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    return rv

if __name__== '__main__':
    app.run()


def get_db():
    """opens a new db connection if there is none yet for the cyrrent app"""
    if not hasattr(g, 'sqlite_db'):
        g.sqlite_db = connect_db()
        return g.sqlite_db

@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_db(error):
    """closes the db again at the end of the request."""
if hasattr(g, 'sqlite_db'):
    g.sqlite_db.close()

def init_db():
    with app.app_context():
        db = get_db()
        with app.open_resource('schema.sql', mode='r') as f:
            db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
        db.commit()


@app.route('/')
def show_entries():
    db_get_db()
    cur = db.execute('select title, text from entries order by id desc')
    entries = cur.fetchall()
    return render_template('show_entries.html', entries=entries)

@app.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
def add_entry():
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        abort(401)
    db = get_db()
    db.execute('insert into entries (title, text) values (?,?)',
        [request.form['title'], request.form['text']])
    db.commit()
    flash('New entry was successfully posted')
    return redirect(url_for('show_entries'))

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['username'] != app.config['USERNAME']:
            error = 'Invalid username'
        elif request.form['password'] != app.config['PASSWORD']:
            error = 'Invalid password'
        else:
            session['logged_in'] = True
            flash('You were logged in')
            return redirect(url_for('show_entries'))
    return render_template('login.html', error=error)

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('logged_in', None)
    flash('You were logged out')
    return redirect(url_for('show_entries'))
```

This is the console message I get (plus 3 attempts to refresh page):

```
user@user:~/Flask/flaskr$ python flaskr.py
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
 * Restarting with reloader
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2014 15:23:40] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2014 15:23:41] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2014 15:23:42] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Any suggestions on what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You put your `app.run()` call **too early**:

```
if __name__== '__main__':
    app.run()
```

This is executed before any of your routes are registered. Move these two lines to the *end* of your file.

Next, you have the first line in `show_entries()` is incorrect:

```
def show_entries():
    db_get_db()
```

There is no `db_get_db()` function; this should be `db = get_db()` instead.

Answer (score 8):

Happened to me also while following Flask Application Setup [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/factory/) . The error was gone after appending a trailing slash at the end of the route.

```
@app.route('/hello')
    def hello():
        return 'Hello, World!'
```

was changed to

```
@app.route('/hello/')
    def hello():
        return 'Hello, World!'
```

and the problem was solved. Hope it helps for anyone who is searching for a problem like this.

Comment: That’s an entirely different problem from the one stated in the question, where route registrations were simply never reached.

Comment: It's still nice to have it here, because I was encountering exactly this problem when working the tutorial, and by googling for `flask tutorial 404` this question came up as the first result, so  think it will also help other people.

Comment: Just delete your cache and reload the page.

Answer (score -1):

You should delete your cache and reload the page.

- Press "Ctrl" + "Shift" + "i" to open the developer tools
- Right-click on the "reload-icon" (⟳) located to the left of the URL bar
- Select "Clear cache and refresh completely"

[image: Delete Cache and Reload]