# EPIPE(Broken Pipe) Error while converting Python client code to java(android)

Tags: java, android, python, http, python-requests

I was going to make an classifier with `Tensorflow`, so I used the  `flask`and  `requests` library to send files from a client to a flask server running my classifier.

The flask server's code is:

```
# Create flask app
app = Flask(__name__)
# Set upload floder
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = './upload'
# Max content length
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024

app.run(host='0.0.0.0')

@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    # Check file upload field
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        return ''
    file = request.files['file']
    # Return if file does not have name
    if file.filename == '':
        return ''
    # Save in upload folder
    audio_file = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], file.filename)
    file.save(audio_file)
```

The python client's code is:

```
import requests 

url = 'http://www.testurl.com/upload'

files = {'file': open('sound/sample/sample/carhorn/1.wav', 'rb')}
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
print(r.text)
```

I wanted to connect the flask server with an Android device, so I rewrote this Python client code to java. I used the 'okhttp 3.5.0' library to send multipart/form data.

The java client's code is:

```
public void uploadFile(String filepath) throws CustomException {
    String requestURL = "http://www.testurl.com/upload";
    File file = new File(filepath);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("file", file.getName(),
                    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("audio/wav"), file))
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(requestURL)
            .post(requestBody)
            .build();

    Response response = null;

    try {
        response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (response == null || !response.isSuccessful()) {
        Log.w("Server", "Unable to upload to server.");
    } else {
        Log.v("Server", "Upload was successful.");
    }
}
```

But with this code, It makes this 'EPIPE' error:

```
03-12 00:01:59.434 29084-29756/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
    03-12 00:01:59.436 29084-29756/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterSendto(IoBridge.java:542)
    03-12 00:01:59.436 29084-29756/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:511)
    03-12 00:01:59.436 29084-29756/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:500)
    03-12 00:01:59.436 29084-29756/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.-wrap1(PlainSocketImpl.java)
    03-12 00:01:59.437 29084-29756/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketOutputStream.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:266)
    03-12 00:01:59.437 29084-29756/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okio.Okio$1.write(Okio.java:78)
    03-12 00:01:59.437 29084-29756/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okio.AsyncTimeout$1.write(AsyncTimeout.java:179)
    03-12 00:01:59.439 29084-29756/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.java:171)
    03-12 00:01:59.439 29084-29756/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSink.write(RealBufferedSink.java:41)
    03-12 00:01:59.440 29084-29756/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec$FixedLengthSink.write(Http1Codec.java:287)
    03-12 00:01:59.440 29084-29756/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.java:171)
    03-12 00:01:59.440 29084-29756/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSink.writeAll(RealBufferedSink.java:99)
    03-12 00:01:59.440 29084-29756/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RequestBody$3.writeTo(RequestBody.java:118)
    03-12 00:01:59.441 29084-29756/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okhttp3.MultipartBody.writeOrCountBytes(MultipartBody.java:171)
    03-12 00:01:59.441 29084-29756/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okhttp3.MultipartBody.writeTo(MultipartBody.java:113)
    03-12 00:01:59.441 29084-29756/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:48)
    03-12 00:01:59.441 29084-29756/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    03-12 00:01:59.441 29084-29756/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
    03-12 00:01:59.441 29084-29756/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    03-12 00:01:59.442 29084-29756/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    03-12 00:01:59.442 29084-29756/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    03-12 00:01:59.442 29084-29756/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    03-12 00:01:59.442 29084-29756/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    03-12 00:01:59.442 29084-29756/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    03-12 00:01:59.442 29084-29756/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    03-12 00:01:59.443 29084-29756/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
    03-12 00:01:59.444 29084-29756/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    03-12 00:01:59.445 29084-29756/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    03-12 00:01:59.445 29084-29756/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:179)
    03-12 00:01:59.446 29084-29756/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:63)
    03-12 00:01:59.446 29084-29756/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient.SoundAlert.uploadFile(SoundAlert.java:249)
    03-12 00:01:59.446 29084-29756/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient.SoundAlert.copyWaveFile(SoundAlert.java:298)
    03-12 00:01:59.447 29084-29756/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient.SoundAlert.stopRecording(SoundAlert.java:212)
    03-12 00:01:59.447 29084-29756/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient.SoundAlert.access$400(SoundAlert.java:66)
    03-12 00:01:59.447 29084-29756/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient.SoundAlert$ExampleThread.run(SoundAlert.java:386)
```

Is there a way to fix this error?
Or is there any way to send multipart/form data on android like the Python client code I wrote?

Thanks,

**EDITED**

I edited the `response = client.newCall(request).execute();` in the java client code to

```
client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
    @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

     @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

            Headers responseHeaders = response.headers();
            for (int i = 0, size = responseHeaders.size(); i < size; i++) {
                System.out.println(responseHeaders.name(i) + ": " + responseHeaders.value(i));
            }

            System.out.println(response.body().string());
        }
    }
    );
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

but still makes this error:

```
03-12 22:05:59.565 26156-26525/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
03-12 22:05:59.565 26156-26525/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterSendto(IoBridge.java:546)
03-12 22:05:59.565 26156-26525/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:515)
03-12 22:05:59.565 26156-26525/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:504)
03-12 22:05:59.565 26156-26525/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$100(PlainSocketImpl.java:37)
03-12 22:05:59.565 26156-26525/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketOutputStream.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:266)
03-12 22:05:59.565 26156-26525/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okio.Okio$1.write(Okio.java:78)
03-12 22:05:59.565 26156-26525/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okio.AsyncTimeout$1.write(AsyncTimeout.java:179)
03-12 22:05:59.575 26156-26525/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.java:171)
03-12 22:05:59.575 26156-26525/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSink.write(RealBufferedSink.java:41)
03-12 22:05:59.575 26156-26525/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec$FixedLengthSink.write(Http1Codec.java:287)
03-12 22:05:59.575 26156-26525/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.java:171)
03-12 22:05:59.575 26156-26525/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSink.writeAll(RealBufferedSink.java:99)
03-12 22:05:59.575 26156-26525/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RequestBody$3.writeTo(RequestBody.java:118)
03-12 22:05:59.575 26156-26525/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okhttp3.MultipartBody.writeOrCountBytes(MultipartBody.java:171)
03-12 22:05:59.575 26156-26525/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okhttp3.MultipartBody.writeTo(MultipartBody.java:113)
03-12 22:05:59.575 26156-26525/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:48)
03-12 22:05:59.575 26156-26525/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
03-12 22:05:59.575 26156-26525/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
03-12 22:05:59.575 26156-26525/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
03-12 22:05:59.575 26156-26525/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
03-12 22:05:59.575 26156-26525/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
03-12 22:05:59.575 26156-26525/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
03-12 22:05:59.575 26156-26525/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
03-12 22:05:59.575 26156-26525/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
03-12 22:05:59.575 26156-26525/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
03-12 22:05:59.575 26156-26525/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
03-12 22:05:59.575 26156-26525/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
03-12 22:05:59.575 26156-26525/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
03-12 22:05:59.575 26156-26525/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:179)
03-12 22:05:59.575 26156-26525/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:129)
03-12 22:05:59.575 26156-26525/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
03-12 22:05:59.575 26156-26525/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
03-12 22:05:59.575 26156-26525/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
03-12 22:05:59.575 26156-26525/com.ishs.fylproject.classifierclient W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Is this code in an AsyncTask? `execute()` of OkHttp cant run on the UI thread

Comment: @cricket_007 Oh.. is that was the problem? I'll try it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just try `client.newCall(request).enqueue(...` for now

Comment: @cricket_007 Still not working..

Comment: I changed `response = client.newCall(request).execute();` to  `client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {...` but, still makes error "EPIPE - Broken Pipe"..

Comment: Sounds like a server side issue to me. Unless the requests code still works fine

Comment: But the python requests client code works quite well though.

Comment: On the server side, the error code is 404. `POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 404 -`

Comment: 404 would be not found, though. Not a server error. Are you sure you are looking at the server logs?

Comment: This is just a flask python server.

Comment: 10.0.1.13 - - [13/Mar/2017 01:12:08] "POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Comment: But like I said, 404 doesn't mean that the server has an error, but that the server doesn't think `/upload` is an available route for a POST request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would get a broken pipe when your flask code returned prematurely.

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0')  # App is running here with no routes

@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    # Check file upload field
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        return ''
    file = request.files['file']
    # Return if file does not have name
    if file.filename == '':
        return ''
```

Both the `return ''` or at the end of the function, you return None with no explicit return type, so OkHttp can't really know if a `response.isSuccessful()` is true although an empty string would probably be a 200 response code in Flask.

It would be better if you can make Flask return actual `Response` objects that have meaningful messages so that you can debug the error better.

---

Secondly, you need to move the `app.run()` statement to the end of all the routes, otherwise, it's not setup correct.

[Flask tutorial - 404 Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25383187/flask-tutorial-404-not-found)

---

I'm not entirely sure that you need a multipart request, though.

You can post a file directly. See https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/PostFile.java

Comment: I think my python server has a problem. When I remove the `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')`and send from localhost, It works very well, but when I put that code(app.run), It makes `('Connection aborted.', error(32, 'Broken pipe'))` this error.

Comment: You need `0.0.0.0` for the server to be globally visible. Your Android app doesn't send to `localhost`, because that would be the Android device **itself**

Comment: Oh, this is finally solved. I moved the code `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')` last line of my python code, and It worked!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25383187/flask-tutorial-404-not-found This helped me to move the code `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')`. Thanks for adding comments on my question!

Comment: Oh, yeah. Completely read over that... But I was kind of correct. Your code was running "prematurely"